# Finding a basis for this matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find all eigenvalues and a basis for each eigenspace of 
$$
A= \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I have found that my eigenvalues are 1 (multiplicity 3). I know that

$$
A-I= \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
but what would the basis for $I$ be?

Comment: Do you know how to find the kernel (nullspace) of a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following are equivalent for any vector $x:$

- $Ax=1x$
- $Ax=x$
- $Ax=Ix$
- $Ax-Ix=0$
- $(A-I)x=0$

Take an arbitrary $x$ and multiply by $A-I$ on the left, then set the result equal to the zero vector. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

The basis of the 1-eigenspace is $(e_1,e_2)$

Please note that the $dim(E_1) < 3$ because the only matrix with $dim(E_1)=3$ is the identity.

As $e_1, e_2$ are clearly independant eigenvector, they are a basis of the eigenspace